# Router reboots when using Nmap

Tags: nmap, router

When I scan an external IP address with Nmap my router always reboots itself, sometimes I even have to manually restart it by using the power switch.

The command I usually use is:

```
nmap -p 1-65535 -T4 -A -v -Pn *IP address*
```

I'm using an Asus RT-AC66U with the latest firmware. I have also tried using the Asuswrt-Merlin firmware but the result is still the same.

Has anyone else experienced this problem and solved it?

Comment: Maybe try [rate limiting](https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably exhausting the router's resources, primarily the NAT table. Every outgoing connection maps your scanning machine's private IP address and source port onto a new source port on the router's public IP address. Since there are more IP address + source port combinations than there are source  ports on the single public IP, the router has to do extra work to avoid collisions. Ideally, this would not cause a reboot or a crash, but home routers are not ideal pieces of equipment.

The easiest way to slow your scan down to something your router can handle would be to change `-T4` to `-T3` (the default). If that doesn't work, continue reducing the [timing options](https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html) until you get a good result. The other thing that can help if you are scanning more than one known-alive IP address is to [not use -Pn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235329/nmap-scan-takes-50-minutes/235462#235462).

Answer (score 0):

Personally haven't used Nmap in a while but it sounds like you're unintentionally DoSing yourself?  Does the aggressive (-A) parameter not overwrite -T4 and just scan as fast as possible?  If that's the case, it's pretty easy to UDP flood home routers.

Definitely sounds like a timing issue though.  Look up the aggressive parameter and take what you need from it (it uses 4-5 flags that you can set manually anyway) and from there, play with rate limiting and possibly maximum transmission unit.

Comment: `-A` has nothing to do with timing. It stands for "advanced" and is equivalent of `-sV -sC -O --traceroute` but skips `-O` and `--traceroute` if you do not have sufficient privileges. You are confusing it with `-T aggressive`, which is equivalent to `-T4`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  For some reason I recalled -A using -T4/5 automatically for whatever reason.  Thanks for clearing that up.